# Expanding/substituting variables in a popen call

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to call some shell program that use the environment and I'm trying to figure out the correct way. I boiled down to this snippet:

```
import subprocess as sp

p = sp.Popen(["echo","Hello","$FOO"], env = {"FOO":"42"}, stdout = sp.PIPE, shell = True)
p.wait()
print(p.communicate())
```

When "shell" is set to True it prints "('\n', None)" and when it's set to False it prints "('Hello $FOO\n', None)", but I was expecting it to print something along the lines of "('Hello 43\n', None)". What I'm doing wrong and is there a better way to do it?

Comment: to expand envvar in the parent: `os.path.expandvars("$PATH also works on windows")`

Comment: [Don't use a list argument to specify the command for subprocess.Popen  together with `shell=True`](http://bugs.python.org/issue21347)

Comment: don't use `stdout=PIPE` unless you read from `p.stdout` later. Remove `p.wait()`: it may deadlock your program if the child process generates enough output to fill the pipe buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
p = sp.Popen("echo Hello $FOO", env={"FOO":"42"}, shell=True)
```

The output should be "Hello 42"

Comment: On Windows (Win7, Python 3.4.4), only `%FOO%` is expanded correctly.